# MSBuild GenerateResources - MSB3554: Cannot write to the output file Resources.resx. A null reference or invalid value was found

Tags: msbuild, mono

I'm attempting to compile a .NET program on Linux ([Nexus Mod Manager](https://github.com/Nexus-Mods/Nexus-Mod-Manager)), but I keep encountering a single error related to a resource file. The exact error message is as follows:

```
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3069,5): error MSB3554: Cannot write to the output file "/home/max/git/Nexus-Mod-Manager/Stage/obj/Debug/Nexus.Client.Properties.Resources.resources". A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter] [/home/max/git/Nexus-Mod-Manager/NexusClient/NexusClient.csproj]
```

I don't know enough about the .NET toolchain to determine what the exact problem is, as the error message only references [this file](https://github.com/Nexus-Mods/Nexus-Mod-Manager/blob/a841eff2b786090c3d421fed709c08a58da93abf/NexusClient/Properties/Resources.resx), and Google has been little help - I've encountered only one other instance of this particular error, and it provided no leads. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had glossed over the line before the error, which was:

```
** (process:7084): WARNING **: 15:40:35.709: PNG images with 64bpp aren't supported by libgdiplus.
```

I realized my mistake after bisecting the resource files included in the `Resources.resx` file and discovering which one it was. Re-rendering the problem image in GIMP resolved the issue.